# How to add an OrderingFilter to existing filters and render them as links

Tags: django, wagtail, django-filter

I'm using [django-filter](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/index.html) for filtering posts of a Django [wagtail](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/) index page via the django-filter's `LinkWidget`. That works fine, just like in the django admin interface with `list_filter`.

Now I would like to expose the functionality to sort/order the queryset by some criteria. Django-filter does provide an `OrderingFilter` ([ref](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ref/filters.html#orderingfilter)) - but I do not know how to implement this filter and achieve a `LinkWidget`-like rendering.

My current approach:

```
# filters.py
class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    categories = PatchedAllValuesFilter(
        name="categories__slug",
        label="Categories",
        widget=LinkWidget(),
        choice_name="categories__name",
    )

    ordering = django_filters.OrderingFilter(
        widget=LinkWidget,
        fields=(
            ('title', 'title')
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = PostPage
        fields = ['categories']
```

---

```
# views.py
from .models import PostPage
from .filters import PostFilter

filter = PostFilter(request.GET, queryset=all_posts)
filter_ordering = PostFilter(request.GET, queryset=all_posts).filters['ordering']

context = self.get_context(request)
context['filter'] = filter
context['filter_ordering'] = filter_ordering

return render(request, self.template, context, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

```
# template.html
<ul>
{% for choice in filter_ordering.field.choices %}
    <li>{{ choice }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

... but this does not work. I do get something from my `OrderingFilter`:

```
('', '---------')
('title', <django.utils.functional.lazy.<locals>.__proxy__ object at 0x7f0d3e021cc0>)
('-title', 'Title (descending)')
```

... and how to render this as links in my template?

Grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just render the form field as usual. Using django-filter's own test models for example,

```
from django_filters import FilterSet, filters, widgets
from tests import models

class F(FilterSet):
    o = filters.OrderingFilter(fields=['id', 'name'], widget=widgets.LinkWidget)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Article
        fields = []

print(F().form['o'])
```

The above generates the following HTML:

```
<ul id="id_o">
    <li><a class="selected" href="?o=">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="?o=id">Id</a></li>
    <li><a href="?o=-id">Id (descending)</a></li>
    <li><a href="?o=name">Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="?o=-name">Name (descending)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it! For the sake of completeness, here's (one possible) Django template snippet: `{% for order_by in filter.form.ordering %}
    {{ order_by }}
{% endfor %}`